Elastic scattering and conservation of spin
I am trying to understand conservation of spin in QED elastic scattering in these nice notes (VJ Martin, Particle Physics, Spring 2012, University of Edinburgh): https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~vjm/Lectures/SHParticlePhysics2012_files/PPLecture6.pdf
On p9, it states that at high energies, helicity is conserved, and that there are therefore only 4 possible spin contributions (uu->uu, ud->ud, dd->dd and du->du), implying the spins of the individual particles are conserved.
Why is this the case?  If helicity is conserved, wouldn't ud->du (all helicities equal to 1) work as well in the center of momentum?

At high energies, particles are effectively massless and their intrinsic spin is equal to their helicity: the helicity is fixed in all possible reference frames.
For a massive particle travelling along $z$ at some speed $v\ll c$, then you can always boost yourself to a frame where the particle is moving along $-z$ at some other speed $v'\ll c$, and its helicity will have flipped. If, however, you go to the high energy regime, then the particle is effectively massless and travels at $v = c$, meaning there is no boost you can perform to flip the helicity.
This tells us that the helicity must be conserved for each particle, as well as the total helicity being conserved.

Thanks!  I understand that you cannot change the helicity of a massless free particle.  But how does that apply to scattering like here?  In the center of momentum, the scattering is a rotation of the momenta.  So the momenta of the particles can be reversed, for instance.  If helicity is conserved, doesn't that mean the spins flip?

The helicity operator of each particle commutes with the Hamiltonian (that generates scattering) and is Lorentz invariant for massless particles: there is no frame in which the helicity flips.
